# Order the following functions by rate of growth

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

How can I order the following functions by rate of growth? n^(logn), 3^n, (logn)^n, n choose n-4, and n^3 ?

What I have is: n^3, n choose n-4, n^logn, 3^n, (logn)^n but I'm not sure if this is right.

Comment: Please add a comma between 3^n and (logn)^n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ordering looks correct to me.

1. `n^3` is obviously the smallest polynomial in the list.
2. `n choose (n-4)` is `n! / ((n-4)! 4!)` = `n (n-1) (n-2) (n-3) / 4!`. It's `O(n^4)`, and is the second smallest function.
3. `n^log n` = `exp((log n)^2)` is not even exponential, it's quasi-polynomial.
4. `3^n` is classical exponential.
5. `(log n)^n` obviously grows faster than `3^n` since it has both base and power increasing as `n` grows. By the way, it's still exponential because `(log n)^n` = `exp(n log log n)` = `O(exp(n^2))`, for example.